# How do I insert a "non-printable" space in a string in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join, non-printing-characters

How can I insert a non-printable single character space into a string? I need to make sure the following JOIN returns no result. If this JOIN returns a match, this would be false positive.

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE (Title VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @table1 (Title)
VALUES ('EhghjgVjhjP') -- Title - varchar(20)

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (Keyword VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @Table2 (Keyword)
VALUES ('E V P') -- Keyword - varchar(20)

SELECT B.Keyword
FROM @table1 A 
INNER JOIN @Table2 B ON A.Title LIKE '%' + REPLACE(B.Keyword, ' ', '%') + '%'
```

Comment: Probably by using the `char` function.

Comment: Thanks @DaleK. I didn't know about this function before. I see CHAR(32) inserts a single space as I wished.